# How to establish the maximum bitmap size for a widget's RemoveViews when using a Glide to fit a memory restriction

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-glide

I see a lot of errors in firebase:

usually happen on low memory devices

```
RemoteViews for widget update exceeds maximum bitmap memory usage (used: 31961088, max: 9216000)

com.bumptech.glide.request.target.AppWidgetTarget.update (AppWidgetTarget.java:124)
com.bumptech.glide.request.target.AppWidgetTarget.setBitmap (AppWidgetTarget.java:141)
com.bumptech.glide.request.target.AppWidgetTarget.onResourceReady (AppWidgetTarget.java:131)
com.bumptech.glide.request.target.AppWidgetTarget.onResourceReady (AppWidgetTarget.java:22)
com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady (SingleRequest.java:657)
com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady (SingleRequest.java:596)
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.callCallbackOnResourceReady (EngineJob.java:159)
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$CallResourceReady.run (EngineJob.java:428)
```

Widget code, I used a Glide to load and set image:

```java
        AppWidgetTarget awt = new AppWidgetTarget(context, R.id.imageView, views, appWidgetId);
        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.appwidget_bg)
                .error(R.drawable.appwidget_bg);
        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load("https://test.com/big_image.png")
                .apply(options)
                .into(awt);
```

One important thing that widget can be unlimited resizable (really big)

I saw what developer.google.com said about it, it not enough for me:

> The total Bitmap memory used by the RemoteViews object cannot exceed that required to fill the screen 1.5 times, ie. (screen width x screen height x 4 x 1.5) bytes.

#### I don't understand how calculate bitmap size to fit memory limitation :(

Comment: Did you find the answer? It looks like we need logic that can count the size for all bitmaps or images on the widget. Perhaps LruCache